# Gradle build failed with invalid method attribute name index 11190

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I closed Android Studio, then open it again and tried to run the app and suddenly for some reason gradle build fails.

This is the error:

> Error:Invalid method attribute name index 11190 in class file org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultTaskCollection

Why?

Comment: Try File->Invalidate Caches /Restart ..

Comment: I have tried, but still the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: What are the recent changes you did to your gradle files or gradle setting in your IDE? Nothing? Are you using the default gradle wrapper on IDE?

Comment: I had nothing changed in Gradle. Tried to localize the app, but added wrong values folder and edited strings with translation tool, but then realized that I typed wrong local name, so deleted it.